# Inicialización de variables en Python usando una función separada de main()

Tags: python, variables

Para inicializar algunas variables en un programa escrito en Python (de forma estructurada, sin usar programación orientada a objetos), quiero utilizar una función denominada *inicializacion()*, a la cual se invoca desde una función *main()*. El problema es el ámbito de estas variables, ya que si les doy su valor inicial en la función *inicializacion()*, al tratar de usarlas en la función *main()* se va a generar un error porque allí no existen. Por ejemplo:

```
import serial

def inicializacion():
    puerto = '/dev/ttyACM0'
    baudRate = 115200
    buffer = ''
    ser = serial.Serial(puerto, baudRate, timeout=1)


def main():
    inicializacion()
    buffer = buffer + leerDatos(ser)
```

¿Qué alternativas hay para evitar el uso de "global" en la función de inicialización? ¿Es posible implementar alguna solución sin tener que pasar las variables como argumentos y sin tener que devolverlas en el "return"?

Comment: Necesitas que sean variables? porque en general un puerto y un rate son constantes

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer sería al estilo de Django, un archivo de configuración con las variables e importarlo cuando sea necesario.

Comment: Existe alguna razón por la que no quieras usar OOP?

Comment: El return de una función es perfectamente valido en la programación Estructurada. Las variables tiene un scope (ámbito) y "pasar" valores entre ámbitos implica usar alguna directiva particular del lenguaje (global, return, pasaje de argumentos a funcion). A veces existe código heredado donde ciertas cuestiones no son factibles, pero dudo que tengas un problema donde no se puede aplicar ningún concepto clásico del ámbito de las variables.

Comment: No creo que sea posible tal cual lo pides. Pero como ya muchos respondieron tienes varias opciones como usar un archivo que contenga las variables y cargarlo bajo demanda. O bien retornar las variables que necesites en un diccionario.

Comment: Haciendo una analogía con la programación orientada a objetos, podríamos ver la definición de una función como la definición de una **clase** y la ejecución de esa función como una **instantación** de esa clase, instancia que llamamos normalmente **clausura**. Cuando la función retorna, desaparece la clausura y con ella los atributos/variables.

Tienes dos soluciones:

 1. emplear al completo la OOP y crear una clase e instanciarla
 2. emplear atributos estáticos de función como si se tratara de una clase

Comment: Nunca me acostumbré a usar OOP, por eso preguntaba por alternativas en programación estructurada. Había pensado lo del diccionario pero no lo del archivo de configuración. Muchas gracias a todos por las ideas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pues, no creo que esto sea posible sin recurrir a la altamante no recomendada `global`. El caso específico que muestras aplica perfectamente en la Programación Orientada a Objetos, sería bueno que expliques la razón por la cual estás tratando de evitarla:

```
import serial


class Clase():
    def __init__(self, puerto, baud_rate, buffer) # inicializacion()
        self.puerto = puerto
        self.baud_rate = baud_rate
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.serial = serial.Serial(puerto, baudRate, timeout=1)

    def leer_datos(self):
        # Tu código
```

Si estas intentando usar los parámetros de configuración, podrías crear un archivo específico el cual será importado a demanda:

*settings.py*

```
puerto = '/dev/ttyACM0'
baudRate = 115200
buffer = ''
```

*main.py*

```
import serial
import settings


def main():
    ser = serial.Serial(settings.puerto, settings.baudRate, timeout=1)
    buffer = settings.buffer + leerDatos(ser)
```

Otra opción es la mencionada por @Carlangueitor en la cual tu configuración la mueves a un archivo `.env` dentro de tu proyecto y así evitas exponer la configuración en uno de los archivos. Puedes usar [dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv).

Answer (score 9):

Creo que podrías utilizar un diccionario. Puedes pasar el diccionario, así como devolverlo, manteniendo los cambios que realices en su interior. Fíjate en el siguiente código.

```
def inicializacion():
    toret = {}
    toret["puerto"] = '/dev/ttyACM0'
    toret["baudRate"] = 115200
    toret["buffer"] = ''

    return toret


def main():
    datos = inicializacion()
    datos["buffer"] = "hola"
    print(datos["buffer"])
    print(datos)

main()
```

Tienes el código aquí: http://ideone.com/BjQyuX
Espero que te resulte útil.

Answer (score 4):

La forma más sencilla y pythonica, adaptando tu propio código:

```
import serial

def inicializacion(puerto='/dev/ttyACM0', baudRate=115200):
    ser = serial.Serial(puerto, baudRate, timeout=1)
    return ser


def main():
    ser = inicializacion()
    buffer=''
    buffer = buffer + leerDatos(ser)

    # El puerto se ha de cerrar para evitar fugas de memoria..
    ser.close()
```

Lo ideal sería cambiarle el nombre de `inicializacion` a otro más expresivo y explícito como p.ej.: `inicializacion_puerto_serie`

Al pasar los valores a la función `inicializacion` como parámetros por defecto se puede reutilizar el código con otro puerto u otro `baud_rate` diferente.

No te olvides nunca cuando abras un fichero o un puerto serie (que para el sistema es lo mismo) de cerrarlo correctamente para evitar fugas de memoria.

Answer (score 3):

Te propongo lo siguiente:

```
import serial

puerto='/dev/ttyACM0'
baudRate=115200

def main():
    buffer=''
    serial.Serial(puerto, baudRate, timeout=1)
    buffer=buffer+leerDatos(str)
```

Comment: Esta es la forma tradicional, no creo que sea lo que el intenta hacer

Comment: Puedo que no pero no responde a los comentarios, es muy amplia la pregunta